# android:windowContentOverlay dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i change that value in java file?

> android:windowContentOverlay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a new drawable programmatically you can do this: `((FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT)). setForeground(yourDrawable);`